# data.table() gives spurious results depending on column order

Tags: r, data.table, gmp, cbind

I created a ten-row dataframe, then converted it to a datatable. I created it again with a different order of columns. When I converted it to datatable, the result was spurious.

```
    c <- pi
    e <- paste("lotsa text, line", as.character(1:10))
    g <- 987654321L
    a <-  raw(length = 10)

    df <- cbind.data.frame(c, e, g, a, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    str(df)

    z <- c(rep(as.bigz("123456789012345678901234567890123456"), times = 10))
    df[,4] <- z
    str(df)
    dt <- data.table(df)
    str(dt)
```

I get what I expected.
`Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  4 variables:`

```
    df <- cbind.data.frame(a, c, e, g, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    str(df)

    df[,1] <- z
    str(df)
    dt <- data.table(df)
    str(dt)
```

This time I get a bonus, 234 extra rows: 
`Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 244 obs. of  4 variables:`

I'm not sure I'm willing to put any faith in this sequence of commands. What is the alternative? At least `cbind.data.frame` doesn't coerce the columns as `cbind` does.

Comment: It will be inefficient to work with and won't print nicely, but a list column could hold it: `data.table(a, c, e, g, z = lapply(z, list))`. By the way, even though you have the tags, it's common to write the library calls into the example so people can just copy paste the whole thing.